# How to disable checkbox inside gridview in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi I am developing one asp.net application with the help of jquery. I have one gridview in my application. It has got checkboxes for each row. Along with checkbox i am binding some values to hidden fields.
This is my gridview code.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Name")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
```

Above code renders output as for example

```
           Name
   chkbox  Andy
   chkbox  Marry
   chkbox  Daniel
```

I am binding same Name(used in Boundfield) to hiddenfield also. I have one dropdown with multiselect feature. Whenever i select Andy from dropdown then i want to disable the Andy checkbox in gridview. I am trying as below. I am getting dropdownselected value in first array and all the hidden value fields in second array. I am pushing common elements to third array.
This is my code.

```
 var result = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < ResultArrayFirst.length; i++) {
                if (selected.indexOf(ResultArrayFirst[i]) >= 0) {
                    result.push(ResultArrayFirst[i]);
                }
            }
```

For example, result array will contain values such as Andy,Marry. In this case i want to disable the checkbox from grid which is left to Andy and Mary. I tried my level best and could not fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lt.

I tried as below.

```
for (var k = 0; k < result.length; k++)
            {
                $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {

                    if($(this).val()==result[k])
                    {

                       //Not sure how to hide disable checkbox GridView1.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = true;
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
```

this is not working still. Need any help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to eliminate most of your example for the sake of clarity.  Once you see what's going on you can put back what you need.

#### First, the big picture:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="user_name" SortExpression="user_name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <input id="CheckBox1" runat="server" type="checkbox" 
           class="cbName" cbid='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' />

        <label id="Label1" runat="server" for="CheckBox1" >
           <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user_name") %>'></asp:Literal>
        </label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="10"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="user_name" DataValueField="user_id" >
</asp:ListBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#ListBox1").on("change", function () {
      $("#ListBox1 option").each(function (i,e) {
        var s = "input.cbName[cbid='" + $(this).val() + "']";
        $(s).prop("disabled", e.selected);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

#### What's going on:

The jquery is monitoring the ListBox for selection changes.

Each time a list item is selected I loop through the entore set of list items and build a jquery selector that looks like this.

> `input.cbName[cbid=XXX]` *where XXX is some index value*

1. `cbName` is unique to the Gridview
2. `cbid` is unique to each name on the GridView and pairs with the ListItem `value` property

This will find, and act, on each item in the gridview that pairs with its associated list item.  This is done to avoid the problems associated with finding gridview items due to the name mangling that comes with ASP server controls.

The following snippet shows an example rendered GridView and Listbox with working jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ListBox1 option").on("click", function() {

    $("#ListBox1 option").each(function(i, e) {
      var s = "input.cbName[cbid='" + $(this).val() + "']";
      $(s).prop("disabled", e.selected);
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#gv,#lb {
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input.cbName[disabled],
input.cbName[disabled] + label{
  cursor:not-allowed;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gv">
  <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">user_name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl02$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_0" class="cbName" cbid="3032">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_0" for="CheckBox1">ALEXIS</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl03$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_1" class="cbName" cbid="1995">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_1" for="CheckBox1">ALI</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl04$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_2" class="cbName" cbid="2311">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_2" for="CheckBox1">ALMAZAR</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl05$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_3" class="cbName" cbid="1884">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_3" for="CheckBox1">ALTSHULER</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl06$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_4" class="cbName" cbid="3267">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_4" for="CheckBox1">ALTSHULER</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl07$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_5" class="cbName" cbid="1742">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_5" for="CheckBox1">ANTHONY</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl08$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_6" class="cbName" cbid="1697">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_6" for="CheckBox1">ANTHONY</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl09$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_7" class="cbName" cbid="2003">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_7" for="CheckBox1">BAEZ</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl10$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_8" class="cbName" cbid="2569">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_8" for="CheckBox1">BALDWIN</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="GridView1$ctl11$CheckBox1" type="checkbox" id="GridView1_CheckBox1_9" class="cbName" cbid="1863">
            <label id="GridView1_cblbl_9" for="CheckBox1">BRENNAN</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="lb">
  <select size="10" name="ListBox1" multiple="multiple" id="ListBox1">
    <option value="3032">ALEXIS</option>
    <option value="1995">ALI</option>
    <option value="2311">ALMAZAR</option>
    <option value="1884">ALTSHULER</option>
    <option value="3267">ALTSHULER</option>
    <option value="1742">ANTHONY</option>
    <option value="1697">ANTHONY</option>
    <option value="2003">BAEZ</option>
    <option value="2569">BALDWIN</option>
    <option value="1863">BRENNAN</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is what i need. Thank you for your effort in helping me.